# Can I use JPARepository with an Elasticsearch datasource?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can I use an ES data source with JPA Repository? The main reason I ask is that I would like to use the JPA Specification executor for queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. `Specification`and `JpaSpecification` are based on JPA queries which are different than Spring Data Elasticsearch queries.